# If you subclass a model class, the paramerters of the function must be the same type?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to subclass a model class QAbstractListModel, the manual said:

the following functions must be implemented in the model's subclass: flags(), data(), headerData(), rowCount().

The original function is described like this:

```py
QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.rowCount([parent=QModelIndex()])
Return type: int
```

Notice: the parent parameter is a QModelIndex() object. if I write a new rowCount(), the parent parameter must also be a QModelIndex() object? or as long as the return type is int, the parameter doesn't matter?

```py
class myListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Comment: `rowCount()` can be executed by other functions with `QModelIndex()` as parameter so your code could check type of parent and do something with this object. For other types it can do something different. For all types it should return integer value.

Comment: In general copy the signature of the base method since other classes can assume that it is, so in your case you should use: `def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()): return num_rows`

Comment: @furas so the parameter must be a QModelIndex() object?

Comment: no, you can define method which uses different objects. But this method can also be used by other methods in different classes - ie. some widget may use it to know how many rows to draw in window - and it may run it with `QModelIndex()`. So you could use `if isinstance(parent, QModelIndex):` in your method to see what you get.